# Putting two sallen key filters in series

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, analog, filter, active-filter

Can I put two sallen key filters in series without putting a buffer in between them (in order to analyse it mathematically correct)?

I know that when the output impedance of the first sallen key filter is much lower than the input impedance of the first sallen key filter.

Comment: Do you have a specific higher order filter response that is required by the chained result and are, instead, asking how to compose that higher order filter into a successive set of Sallen-Key filters of 2nd order to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output impedance of a Sallen-Key filter is zero, with an ideal op-amp of course, and very close to zero with a real op-amp. One stage can drive another stage without interaction.

Cascading Sallen-Key stages is a standard way to build up a higher order filter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How do I know/prove that the output impedance is zero?

Comment: That comes from op-amp and control theory.  It would be best to start another question to get an answer to that.

Comment: How do you know? Because I told you so. BTW, I also told you that with a real op-amp it's not zero, just very close to zero. Perhaps you mean how do I calculate what the output impedance is? The output impedance is change of voltage for change of current. Now the op-amp can supply arbitrary output current change without change at the input pins (an ideal, infinite gain op-amp anyway) so its output voltage doesn't change either. So zero output impedance. A real opamp needs a sniff of deltaV at the input pins, so the output voltage does change, but with very high gain, it changes very little.

Comment: @JohnD I do know control theory.

Comment: @Neil_UK Yes indeed how do I calculate it?

Comment: That would be in the datasheet for a given op-amp.

Comment: Just search for negative feedback in amplifiers. It clearly shows the impact of the feedback on the input and output impedances.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative-feedback_amplifier

Comment: Real opamps shows a very high open loop gain, hence you can approximate it to about infinite, so the same theory applies to them.